# What is the smallest infinite ordinal that is not order isomorphic to a reordering of the natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, natural-numbers

I've been working on a particular set theory problem for a while and essentially I've hit a roadblock because of this question. I just need to know what this ordinal is, because I have a sneaking suspicion that it might not be omega 1. In fact, if it did end up being a countable ordinal, it would help me immensely.

Comment: Isn't $\alpha$ being order isomorphic to a reordering of $\mathbb N$ equivalent with $\alpha$ and $\mathbb N$ having the same cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\omega_1$. If $\omega \leq \alpha < \omega_1$, then it is countable so if $f :\omega \rightarrow \alpha$ is a bijection, then $(\omega, <_1)$ is order isomorphic to $(\alpha , \in)$ where $m \leq_1 n$ iff $f(m) \in f(n)$. What problem are you working on?

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I've been awake for around 50+ hours and should've known. It's this thing for undergrad research, my adviser told me that the runtime of the algorithm (in number of turns) for this problem had to be a countable ordinal number, but if all countable ordinals are admissible as order types for the naturals then the upper bound is their supremum. Maybe I'm just missing something, I'll work it out.

Comment: Maybe your "run time" ordinals have additional property of being recursive in which case their supremum is the least non recursive ordinal (denoted $\omega_1^{CK}$) which is countable.

Comment: How would I know if they were recursive? Is there a straightforward way of proving that? I ran across the Church-Kleene ordinal while looking for an answer but everything I could find was pretty far above undergrad level.

Comment: I cannot say much until I see what the algorithm is. I mentioned recursive ordinals because they form a natural proper initial segment of countable ordinals.

Comment: Just figured it out actually, just had to write out everything like a Turing machine, everything turned out to be computable. It's $\omega_1^{CK}$.

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition, it is $\aleph_1$, which is also the smallest uncountable cardinal.

Now, you can't go further into the description of it (namely, you cannot tell whether this is or not the continuum cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$): it has been proven that the [continuum hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) is not decidable (that is, may be set either true of false without adding contradictions to the ZFC set of axioms)